# Test case title appears as "feature"in TFS for all the cucumber test scenarios in the project

Tags: tfs, automated-tests, cucumber, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am trying to run a Eclipse java cucumber project in TFS (which has set of feature files).

After running successfully in TFS, the *TestCase* title appears as "feature" for all the *TestCases*. Unable to see which test scenario was run.Though I can see the feature names appearing in the log, those names does not appear in Result. It would be great if someone could help with setting up the *TestCase* title in TFS.

[image: Screenshot below]

Answer (score 1):

Since TFS was picking junit report , I was finding this issue.
I updated my result file pointing to cucumber created junit unit report. It worked fine for me. Updated the test runner file to create the junit report -**"junit:target/surefire-reports/TEST-TestSuite.xml"** and pointed TFS result file to **target/surefire-reports/TEST-TestSuite.xml**.
Code below.

```
    @CucumberOptions(
                features= {"src/test/resources/Features"},
                plugin   = {"pretty:STDOUT","html:Reports/cucumber-pretty",**"junit:target/surefire-reports/TEST-TestSuite.xml"**,               "com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:Reports/Reporting/Quixxi_Report.html"},
                monochrome = true,
                dryRun=false
           )
```